# Finding a subspace of image of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question is:

> Consider the linear transformation $L: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 : (x,y,z) \mapsto (2x+y-z,y-2z,-2x-z)$. When $U = \text{Span}\{(0,0,1),(1,1,1)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear subspace of $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^3,+)$, what is $\{v \in \mathbb{R}^3 | L(v) \in U\}$?

I've been searching for quite a while now, thinking that I should find $\{X | L_\beta^\beta X \in \text{Span}\{(0,0,1),(1,1,1)\}\}$ ($\beta$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$). I found that $L_\beta^\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 2&1&-1\\0&1&-2\\-2&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, where the columns are the images of the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So I tried to solve:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2&1&-1\\0&1&-2\\-2&0&-1\end{pmatrix} X = \lambda_1 \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} + \lambda_2\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

This gave me a set of solutions with one free variable and $\lambda_2$ in it (I found $ V = \text{Span} \{ (\frac{3}{2}\mu,\lambda_2 + 2\mu,\mu) | \mu \in \mathbb{R} \}  $), but I have no idea what to do with it now.

The answer is $\text{Span}\{(-1,4,2),(1,0,-2)\}\}$ (not unique of course).

Edit: so looking back at my solution and at the given solution, what I had been doing was not *very* wrong. I should have taken one solution of $\{X | L_\beta^\beta X = (0,0,1)\}$ and one of $\{X | L_\beta^\beta X = (1,1,1)\}$, and then the span of those two is $\{v \in \mathbb{R}^3 | L(v) \in U\}$, since the transformation is linear.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Please dit your question to show the set of equations you arrive at. This counts as showing work and will help others help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this leads to the systems of linear equations  $(2x+y−z,y−2z,−2x−z) = (0,0,1)$ and $(2x+y−z,y−2z,−2x−z) = (1,1,1)$. Then take the span of these solutions giving the span of $\{(−1,4,2),(1,0,−2)\}$.

Comment: That's what I had been doing afterwards, but I made a calculation mistake. Also, I didn't know you could take the span of the answers, but it seems logical since the transformation is linear. Thank you very much.